Automating PGP Encryption/Decryption of text files
I'm setting up an SFTP from an on-premise server to a hosted server. I have the SFTP part figured out to move the files, however what I haven't figured out is the hosted vendors request for PGP encryption and decryption. I'm using WINScp for the SFTP and as far as my research shows there isn't a way to decrypt with WINSCP (I could be wrong). I have figured out how to automate encrypt/decrypt with a username and private key but not with just a private/public keyset. There is also the issue of the file names, when transferring out they would be called something like "FinancialDoc1234167811.txt" or "FinancialDoc109871846.txt". In the batch file I've created you can use winSCP to move these files by using those first words that will stay the same EG: "FinancialDoc*.txt" is there an option in PGP Command Line to do the same for encryption/decryption. Could be better for me to start looking at building something in C# or C++ instead of trying to do this in a batch file. However from what I understand (not much) this seems like something I should be able to do from a batch file.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

As you seem to suggest all files should be gpg encrypted, then you would be better to just encrypt the whole file system.
